# capturing reference cell address by mouse click in excel charts by VBA Pointapi

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am trying to make zoom feature for my Graph Creator macro. I already created the code to change all X and Y axis in the active sheet.

```
Sub change_X_axis()

    Dim myChartObject As ChartObject
    Dim mySrs As Series
    Dim myPts As Points

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each myChartObject In .ChartObjects
            For Each mySrs In myChartObject.Chart.SeriesCollection
            
            'Set the data range
                 mySrs.XValues = "=PT1!$A$964:$A$1911"
            Next
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

```
Sub change_Y_axis()

    Dim myChartObject As ChartObject
    Dim mySrs As Series
    Dim strs() As String
    Dim strs2() As String
    Dim newFormulaY() As String

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each myChartObject In .ChartObjects
            For Each mySrs In myChartObject.Chart.SeriesCollection
            
            strs = Split(mySrs.Formula, ",")
            strs2 = Split(strs(2), "$")
            
            'Set the data range
                 mySrs.Values = strs2(0) & "$" & strs2(1) & "$" & "4:" & "$" & strs2(3) & "$" & "8643"
            Next
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

What I would like to achieve is auto filling of first X and Y axis cell by mouse click on the XY Scatter graph and then I will change the range of the graph by the macros above.

I saw the POINTAPI article of the MS in the link below:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/visual-basic-procedure-to-get-set-cursor-position-1ef41d8b-6348-6ef1-f015-f9119799c65c

However, my need is to catch the reference x axis of a graph like original range is A4:A1400 and I would like to catch the any value within this range by the mouse click.

As I see the POINTAPI is applicable in active sheet and it will the coordinates of an active sheet. But I need reference point within Seriescollection(Chart) object.

Could you please give me a hint about this?

Thanks.

I tried POINTAPI but this is not exactly what I was looking for as described above.